# How to trigger a click event from inside of a click event handler?

Tags: jquery

I have a click event like:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //
  //

  $("#btnSave").trigger("click");
});
```

The above is currently creating a recursive loop and erroring out.

How can I acomplish what I want though?  I want that button to be clicked, but not the fire the same event and get into a recursive situation?

Comment: I don't get why you need the trigger inside of it then?

Comment: What is your intention with this?

Comment: @DHLopez I want the button clicked after I modify the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (untested!):

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e, firstClick) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //
    //

    if (firstClick == undefined) {
        $("#btnSave").trigger("click", [true]);
    }
});
```

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Javascript set timeout seems like it would do well for you. It delays running code until a set amount of time. See my example below:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //The line below starts the timeout function
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("#btnSave").trigger("click"); //Your code
  }, 3000); //3000 is how long the code is delayed to run in ms (3000 is 3 seconds)

});
```

If you only want this function to run once you can make a variable to act as a on/off switch preventing multiple firings of the function. Please let me know if you want to do that and I'll write the simple code needed to set that up.